# moving photo tab on a Facebook page

Tags: tabs, facebook-page

I am an administer to a Facebook Page, and it has come up that the photos tab part of the toolbar is not where I would like to have it. I want to move it so that a user sees it when they click the down arrow to the right of the tabs. Moving the Likes tab was quite simple, but for some reason the Photos tab does not have that option. Is there a way to move the Photos tab, either through some type of GUI or coding that I could possibly do with the Facebook Page?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, the Photos tab is not adjustable.

Comment: Matthew can you please provide source for your answer?

Comment: No, this information is now out-of-date because Facebook Pages have been redesigned since I answered.